# how to trigger the image in ember with handlebars

Tags: javascript, image, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

Hello I want to appear the image from code i wrote below but i cant. Any ideas?
I googled and i found that i must use a helper function.

(template)
showallapps.hbs

```
{{#if getappsexist}}
    {{#each app in getapp}}
       {{#each app.app_files}}
        {{#link-to "dashboard" app}}
            <img {{bind-attr src=get_url}} class="img-responsive">
        {{/link-to}}
        {{/each}}
        {{#link-to "dashboard" app}}
            {{app.app_name}}
        {{/link-to}}
```

(controller)
showallapps.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  apps:[],

   getappsexist: function () {
    var appsexist = false;
    if (this.store.all('userapp').content.length > 0) {
        appsexist = true;
    }
    return appsexist;
}.property(),

getapp: function () {
   this.apps = this.store.all('userapp');
   return this.apps;
}.property(),

get_url: function (){  
  var url = 'http://' + JSON.parse(this.apps.content[2]._data.app_files).url;
  return url;  
}.property()

});
```

I have this json.

```
{
    "userapp": [
        {

        }, 
        {  
           "app_files": "{"url":"static.xxx.xxx/data/application/3911efd9-413a-11e1-b5e9-fbed80c8f6ba/eleutheris_epilogis.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","name":"eleutheris epilogis.jpg"}" 
        } 
     ]
}
```

I get these errors:
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed {"url":"static.xxx.xxx/data/application/3911efd9-413a-11e1-b5e9-fbed80c8f6ba/eleutheris_epilogis.jpg","mime":"image/jpeg","name":"eleutheris epilogis.jpg"}

Comment: This is because `app_files` is not an array, but a hash.

Comment: And how can i fix it?

Comment: Do you intend to return multiple `app_files` from the server?

Comment: Actually, could you describe the whole data model you want to see on the screen? For example: "The user has a list of `userapps`, which has a list of `app_files`. An app file has a `url`", and so on...

Comment: Well, i want to return the corresponding url of app_files for each userapp in my json. Imagine this get_url: function (){  
  var url = 'http://' + JSON.parse(this.apps.content[2]._data.app_files).url;
  return url;  
}.property() with a for-loop i guess, that when finds the url it will bind it.

Comment: The data model is exactly the way you described it.

Comment: Do you have control over the JSON returned from the server, or is it an external service and you can't modify it?

Comment: Anyway, does this look OK to you? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/palayizuxi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: No, because app_files is not an object but a string that's because i deserialize it with json.parse. And i want it to bind inside {{image}}.

Comment: Can you do the JSON-decoding on the server side?

Comment: The core problem is that your JSON is not quite ideal from the client's perspective. It *can* be fixed on the client side, but it'd be much better if you fixed the server instead

Comment: The reason why I asked if you can change your server-side code is precisely because the behavior you described is badly represented in your JSON, and the one I used instead reflects your data model better.

Comment: No i cannot change it. Anyway thanks for your effort.